# Is there VBA function to pull the file name into the code?

Tags: excel, vba

I put together a macro to run stock feed report analysis; however, I've made it specific to a single file. I'm using the file name, and extracting a portion to create a column header. Currently, the code is using a specific file path/file name to complete this task, but I would like to make it a generalized function that can operate on multiple files (each file utilizes the same structure).

I'm not sure where to even start to reference the file name to continue.

```
Dim MyPath As String, mps As Variant, mps_temp As String, mydate As Date, IntroDate As Date, i As Integer

MyPath = "C:\Users\Kirank\Documents\Stock Feed Analysis\HVL_Available_to_Sell_Report_with_Headers 2019.01.01"
mps = Split(MyPath, " ")

For i = LBound(mps) To UBound(mps)
    mps_temp = mps(UBound(mps) - i)
    If mps_temp Like "####.##.##" Then
        mydate = DateSerial(Mid(mps_temp, 1, 4), Mid(mps_temp, 6, 2), Mid(mps_temp, 9, 2))
        IntroDate = mydate - 181
        Exit For
    End If
```

I would like to have code that will pull the file path into the "MyPath" field so that I can use the Split function to then pull the date out of the file name.

Comment: Is this a file you open, or the file containing the macro code?

Comment: @BigBen - It's a file I open, the macro will be stored separately.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope below code will be useful**!

I used Do loop and Dir function so as to loop through all excel files present in hardcoded folder StockAnalysis without hardcoding file name.

```
Dim Mypath As String, fileName As String, mps As Variant, mps_temp As String, mydate As Date, IntroDate As Date, i as integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Mypath = "C:\Users\Kirank\Documents\Stock Feed Analysis\"

fileName = Dir(Mypath & "*.xl?")    'Dir functions support use of wildcards character * and ? used to look for all types of excel files in the folder.


Do While fileName <> ""

Count = Count + 1

mps = Split(fileName, " ")

For i = LBound(mps) To UBound(mps)
  mps_temp = mps(UBound(mps) - i)
    If mps_temp Like "####.##.##.xlsx" Then
      mydate = DateSerial(Mid(mps_temp, 1, 4), Mid(mps_temp, 6, 2),Mid(mps_temp, 9,2))
        IntroDate = mydate - 181      

        Cells(Count, 1).Value = IntroDate    'Saving Introdate in excel, feel free to change the destination.
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

fileName = Dir()

Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry , ignore this answer since I missunderstood the question

You can get the file path by using :

```
MyPath=thisworkbook.path
```

is this useful for you?

Comment: `thisworkbook.path` will get the path of the file containing the macro, not the file opened by the user. `ActiveWorkbook.path` would be a better option and `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` (for a single) file or `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` (for multiple files) may be best, depending on the exact setup of OP

Comment: When I used the suggested, the query output showed 12:00:00 AM. When converted to a date, it comes up with "1/0/1900." The date should be 1/1/2019, the file name uses the following structure: "yyyy.mm.dd."

Comment: @KiranKelkar that `For` loop is unwarranted, as is the `Split` part. Use `StrRev` to get the last index of `.` and trim the file extension away, then grab the `Right`-most 10 characters, and work that 10-char string into a proper `Date`. `1/0/1900 12:00:00 AM` corresponds to the date value `0` in VBA.

Comment: ah ok , sorry I missunderstood the question , related to the date , let's say mypath="my route/myfolder/01.01.2019" , you can get the date using : mydate=mid(mypath,len(mypath) -9 ,2) & "/" & mypath,len(mypath) -6 ,2) & "/" & mypath,len(mypath) -3 ,4)

Comment: @Alvaro CC - It might be worthwhile to [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56484199/edit) before it gets voted down

Comment: If you misunderstood the question and your answer no longer applies, it's recommended to delete it using the 'delete' option underneath.

Comment: Thanks @cybernetic.nomad, I just edited it warning of my error , hope this is ok

Comment: I'm getting an "Expected: end of statement" compile error referencing the "," between the second mypath,len.

Comment: Thanks @TylerH , just deleting

Comment: sorry , just undeleted to answer @KiranKelkar last comment , this should work : mydate=mid(mypath,len(mypath) -9 ,2) & "/" & mid(mypath,len(mypath) -6 ,2) & "/" & mid(mypath,len(mypath) -3 ,4)

Comment: @TylerH ,@cybernetic.nomad not sure whether to delete my answer or not since it will lock comments , sorry for the mess